# Ironpython - Compile to single exe

Tags: .net, ironpython

I compiled with pyc.py my code with the command:

```
ipy.exe "F:\IronPython 2.7\Tools\Scripts\pyc.py" /target:winexe /embed /standalone /platform:x86 /main:"C:\Users\Mito125\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\mst\mst\Program.py" "C:\Users\Mito125\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\mst\mst\MainForm.py"
```

to distribuited a single file without installer. The code works correctly on SharpDevelop or if I launch it with ipy.exe, and compiled exe works correctly on my computer. But if I try to launch on different pc, I get an error.

First I thought python module import was the problem, so I delete all import(like import os), but error remain. How could I compile all dll and script in single exe correctly?

EDIT:I noticed that /embed /standalone parameters don't embed really all necessary dll... If I copy all dll + exe program works well...

Comment: Does it tell you which assemblies it can't find? `/embed /standalone` should include all of the IronPython assemblies, but there's no way to include other assemblies you may need.

Comment: I'd like to create a single exe like c#, and /embed /standalone I tought them did what I needed... Is there a tool to create a single exe with all dll embedded?

Comment: Not right now. 2.7.4 might change that, but for the meantime you could give ILMerge a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, I didn't know it...